# Include part of a PHP file

Tags: php

I have a PHP file (Region.php) and an excerpt of my code is:

```
<?php

/** Create HTTP POST */

$country =  'Australia';

$area =  htmlspecialchars($_POST["area"]);

$seek = '<parameters> 
<row><param>COUNTRY</param><value>'. $country .'</value></row> 
<row><param>AREA</param><value>'. $area .'</value></row>
</parameters>';

$postdata = http_build_query(
array(
 'DistributorKey' => '201201100935',
 'CommandName' => 'GetCities',
 'CommandParameters' => $seek)
);

$opts = array(
'http' => array(
'method'  => 'POST',
'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'content' => $postdata)
);

/** Get string output of XML (In URL instance) */

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result =     file_get_contents('http://national.atdw.com.au/soap/AustralianTourismWebService.asmx/CommandHandler?', false, $context);

/** Change encoding from UTF-16 to Unicode (UTF-8)
Parse unstructured tags */

$result = str_replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>', '', $result);
$result = str_replace('<string    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/soap/AustralianTourismWebService">', '', $result);
$result = str_replace('</string>', '', $result);
$result = str_replace('utf-16', 'utf-8', $result);

$result = simplexml_load_string(trim(html_entity_decode($result)), 'SimpleXMLElement');

/** Instantiate Loop */


foreach ($result->area as $entry) {
echo $entry->attributes()->area_name . "<br /><br />";
}


foreach ($result->area->city as $entry) {

$pna = htmlspecialchars_decode($entry->attributes()->suburb_city_postal_code, ENT_QUOTES);
$pna = str_replace("'", "''", $pna);

$str = htmlspecialchars_decode($entry->attributes()->attribute_id_status, ENT_QUOTES);
$str = str_replace("'", "''", $str);

echo  $pna. "<br />";
echo  $str . "<br />";
echo (string)$entry . "<br /><br />";

}

?>
```

I have another PHP file (Houses.php) but I need only the value of `$entry->attributes()->area_name` in the `Houses.php` file. Excerpt of my code in `Houses.php`:

```
<?php

require_once 'Region.php';


/** Create HTTP POST */
$accomm = 'ACCOMM';
$region = '('$entry->attributes()->area_name')';
$page = '10';
---- some code ---
?>
```

I keep getting errors because it is executes the entire `Region.php` file whereas I only need the value of the `attribute()`.
Please how can I fix this.
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you make functions in the other file, and call those that you want only?

Comment: Don't mess with files. [Use namespaces and a proper application structure](http://www.phptherightway.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can interpret comments as this, as you cannot include only part of a PHP file:

Create a file header.inc.php, not header.inc for security, as one can download a .inc as source file by bad config, but not .php, as executed by apache2 :

```
<?php

/** Create HTTP POST */

$country =  'Australia';

$area =  htmlspecialchars($_POST["area"]);

$seek = '<parameters> 
<row><param>COUNTRY</param><value>'. $country .'</value></row> 
<row><param>AREA</param><value>'. $area .'</value></row>
</parameters>';

$postdata = http_build_query(
array(
 'DistributorKey' => '201201100935',
 'CommandName' => 'GetCities',
 'CommandParameters' => $seek)
);

$opts = array(
'http' => array(
'method'  => 'POST',
'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'content' => $postdata)
);

/** Get string output of XML (In URL instance) */

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result =     file_get_contents('http://national.atdw.com.au/soap/AustralianTourismWebService.asmx/CommandHandler?', false, $context);

/** Change encoding from UTF-16 to Unicode (UTF-8)
Parse unstructured tags */

$result = str_replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>', '', $result);
$result = str_replace('<string    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/soap/AustralianTourismWebService">', '', $result);
$result = str_replace('</string>', '', $result);
$result = str_replace('utf-16', 'utf-8', $result);

$result = simplexml_load_string(trim(html_entity_decode($result)), 'SimpleXMLElement');
?>
```

Shorten the Region.php file:

```
<?php
require_once "header.inc.php";

/** Instantiate Loop */


foreach ($result->area as $entry) {
  echo $entry->attributes()->area_name . "<br /><br />";
}


foreach ($result->area->city as $entry) {
  $pna = htmlspecialchars_decode($entry->attributes()->suburb_city_postal_code, ENT_QUOTES);
  $pna = str_replace("'", "''", $pna);

  $str = htmlspecialchars_decode($entry->attributes()->attribute_id_status, ENT_QUOTES);
  $str = str_replace("'", "''", $str);

  echo  $pna. "<br />";
  echo  $str . "<br />";
  echo (string)$entry . "<br /><br />";

}
?>
```

In House.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'header.inc.php';


/** Create HTTP POST */
$accomm = 'ACCOMM';
$region = "";
foreach ($result->area as $entry) {
  $region = $entry->attributes()->area_name;
  break;
}
$page = '10';
---- some code ---
?>
```

All the tree files must reside in the same directory/folder.

Comment: Your explanation really works and I am about to vote it in. But I still get an error because part of the 'header.inc.php' file includes code that gets data from a form; thus 'houses.php' throws an error. Please see modified code. Thanks

Comment: In the question, $result used in simplexml_load_string(... in the file Region.php is undefined, what's it?

Comment: Please see the entire code for clarification. I have inserted the updated code

Answer (score 0):

Organize your code into functions:

```
myfuncts.php

function fn1() {
  ...stuff...
  ...stuff...
} // fn1()

function fn2() {
  ...things...
  ...things...
} // fn2()
```

Then you can use them by simply calling:

```
require("functions.php");
fn1();
fn3();
```